# assigning a value from one of the parameters in list to a new array

Tags: python, arrays, list, opencv

I am working on a project to detect a car in the video using haar cascade. It's working out fine but it's still bit unstalbe, such as unexpected object which is not a car is detected and vanishes in a matter of a second or two. So I tried to put the logic that is a detected object's coordinate changes abruptly, that is not what we expect, but if it doesn't change much, it is car. So I created the following code

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\bbd3.avi')
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\cars.xml')

i=0
x = [None] * 10000000
y = [None] * 10000000

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    roi_gray = gray[0:480, 100:300]
    roi_color = frame[0:480, 100:300]

    # roi_gray defines area in the video that we will apply haar cascade detection
    # we add roi_color with same area to draw rectangle on the color frame axis

    cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.05, 5, minSize=(30,30) )
    # we can specify the value of certain parameter by mentioned name of that parameter before that value. parameter is image, scalefactor, minneigbors, minsize. 

    for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
        x[i]=x
        y[i]=y
        if i>= 1:
            if abs(x[i]-x[i-1]) < 10 and abs(y[i]-y[i-1]) < 10 :
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)


    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    i=i+1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here detectmultiscale returns list of rectangles where the detected object is located. It's basically to create an empty array and assigning the left bottom coordinate to the array and compare them between consecutive frames. However it keeps returning

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object does not support item assignment
```

So can I get any idea on why this happens in the first place and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

*Also, for those who haven't dealt with opencv before, detectmultiscale returns list of rectangles, but there can be multiple rectangles returned depending on how much objects are detected in the video. For example if one car is detected in the first frame, it returns only one rectangle, but if there are three cars detected in the second frame, it returns three rectangle. I assume this is the main problem here. Assinging multiple values to a one parameter x[i]. However, how can I assign values to a fixed array if I don't know how much data will be given in one frame ?

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: You create a list named `x` first, then name something else `x` in your `for` loop... As these are two different objects, give them different names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing `for (x,y,w,h) in cars`, the object named `x` becomes the `numpy.int32` (an integer) returned by `detectMultiScale`.

Now, when Python arrives to `x[i]=x`, it first evaluates the right value. It's an integer.
Then it tries to "evaluate" the left value, but `3[2]` has no meaning in Python, so it fails.

Here's how I would refactor your code :

```
import cv2

MAX_DIST = 10

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\bbd3.avi')
car_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\cars.xml')

cars_coordinates = []

while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    roi_gray = gray[0:480, 100:300]
    roi_color = frame[0:480, 100:300]

    cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.05, 5, minSize=(30,30) )

    for (x,y,w,h) in cars:
        if cars_coordinates:
            last_x, last_y = cars_coordinates[-1]
            if abs(x - last_x) < MAX_DIST and abs(y - last_y) < MAX_DIST :
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)
                cars_coordinates.append((x,y)) # adding the coordinates here allows to keep track of only your past detected cars


    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

---

Warning on your algorithm : I corrected it as is, but with that algorithm, if the first detection of `detectMultiScale` is a false positive, you won't "get back" to the real cars. Plus, you can only track one car.

Pseudo code for a slightly better algorithm:

```
During 5 frames, only memorize the detected areas

When handling a new frame, for each detected car:
    if the car is near a memorized area in at least 4 of the last 5 frames:
        Consider it as a car
    Append it anyway to the detected areas for this frame
```

Doing like this, you won't miss a new car appearing at the middle of your video, nor loose a car that would not have been detected in one frame for whatever reason, and false positives have good chances to be avoided.

Comment: Oh I was stupid. I'm new to python so still confused with them. And yes, I have actually tested out with the video before writing this and it actually found out car in the first place so I am not worried about that.The problem is as you have mentioned it can only track the car it first detected. Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: One simple way to improve it would be to maintain a list of detected zones (with the zones in the last 10 frames, for instance), then only print the rectangle if it is near say 5 of the memorized zones.

Comment: See the pseudo code I added to my answer for a clearer explanation.